# I'd like to transfer a new folder related to my application, and put the photo taken in the application to this folder

Tags: java, android, xml

This is the function to create my folder and the image

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name


    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyFolder");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "Photo" + timeStamp + "_";

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",
            folder/* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

and this is what's on create

```
mbtnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                   try {
                    createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                onActivityResult(0,0,intent);
            }
    });
```

It's created a .jpg file but unreadeable. When the photo is taken it's also in the camera folder and readable, but unreadable on my new folder. Could somebody explain why?

Comment: Can you first explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: `success = folder.mkdir();`. So you are not checking the return value? Bad!

Comment: `It's created a .jpg file but unreadeable. `. You created an empty file. So with size 0. Is this what you call unreadable?

Comment: `When the photo is taken it's also in the camera folder `. No. The camera app will not write the image to file if you use that intent.

Comment: `but unreadable on my new folder. `. Yes there is still your empty file. Nobody touched it.

Comment: i'd like to transfer my photo to the folder created

Comment: You have no foto. You have no picture. You have no image. There is no image file. Not with the way you used that intent. You on!y got a thumbnail. So there is not much to transfer.

Comment: but with the intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, a pic is taken, how do i transfer it ?

Comment: No. You are wrong. There is no image file. The camera app threw the full image away (well if it had one) and gave you only a thumbnail bitmap in onActivityResult. I said that before.

Comment: But how should i take a photo from the app to transfer it to the new folder ?

Comment: You have not googled for a minute. How to use the camera has been asked and treated a thousand times on stackoverflow. And on a hundred other sites.